# Is there a quick way to determine what tables are referencing a specific primary key as a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm doing a small bit of refactoring, however, I'd like to check to see if the current primary key I'd like to change is currently being referenced as a foreign key in any other tables. The schema I'm working with is quite large so it is not a viable option to scan through each table in the schema.

Comment: If you would like to get this information programmatically, you can check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532023/getschemaforeignkeys-against-sqlclient-doesnt-yield-enough-information/2532034#2532034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXEC sp_help 'yourtable'` - one of the tables in the resultset includes FKs referencing the table.

Comment: ++ great answer. Although the data is not structured, the simplicity does makes me feel a bit goldberg-esque. ;-).

Comment: @code poet - thanks, it always helps to know how to get this stuff in vanilla table format, though - there's nothing quite like a query that returns a result set that itself can be copied + pasted into a query window and run.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this??

```
SELECT
    fk.name,
    t1.name 'Child table',
    t2.name 'Parent table'
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t1 ON fk.parent_object_id = t1.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t2 ON fk.referenced_object_id = t2.object_id 
WHERE 
    t2.name = '(your table name here)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to another possibility:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/61481/